# browser back button doesnt work in cached environment

Tags: browser, caching, button, back

The back button just causes my page to refresh. Is there a way around this without disabling the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your HTML header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: ok will that effect the caching on the page im returning too?

Answer (score 0):

where you click on product/image on page there call onclick javascript function i.e.

```
function getHashOnBack(valueget) 
{
   location.hash = "#backTo=" + $(window).scrollTop();$(document).height();
}
```

Now, put

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 var ab = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("=");
 if (ab[0] == "backTo") 
 {
  // this would be called automatically when back putton pressed and hav #back=1234   etc. // value in url

  $(window).scrollTop(parseInt(ab[1]));
}
}
```